# How to know whether a jar file can be run on Android?

Tags: android, jar, hidden-markov-models

I'm asking this because i want to use [this Hidden Markov Model classifier](https://code.google.com/p/jahmm/) in an android app.
The lib makes no use of any graphical UI so my guess is that I can use just like that?

How to know which jars we can and which not on android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the jars can be used directly in android as Android SDK includes most of Java's standard implementation.

If you use eclipse, if the jar is linked to android unknown element (one of the most common is awt functionnality) you will get an error on creating the .apk